# Non-Zeros of Euler Product Shouldn't Imply $\zeta(s)>0$ for $\sigma>1$

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta, infinite-product

The Riemann Zeta function can be represented by the following series, which has also proven to be equivalent to the infinite product over primes:

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^{s}}=\prod_{p}(1-\frac{1}{p^{s}})^{-1}$$

The above is valid for $\sigma>1$ where $s=\sigma+it$.

A very common statement about $\zeta(s)$ is that it is non-zero for $\sigma>1$. The justification is that each of the factors of the infinite product are (1) non-zero and (2) finite.

**Question:** The justification seems insufficient. What am I missing?

For example, the following infinite product also has factors which are non-zero and finite, and yet the product is widely agreed to be zero (worked out [here](https://fromprimestoriemann.blogspot.com/2020/12/convergence-of-infinite-products.html)).

$$ \prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) = 0$$

Answer (score 3):

It is true that the Euler product shows that $\zeta(s) \neq 0$ for $\mathrm{Re} s > 1$, but the reason is not what you gave. Instead, it's because the product converges absolutely at all.

Note that we say that $\prod_n a_n$ converges if the partial products tend to a **nonzero** limit --- it is necessary both for the partial products to converge to a limit and for the limit to not be zero.

So the statement that $\zeta(s) \neq 0$ for $\mathrm{Re} s > 1$ follows from the Euler product representation is a statement about convergence of the Euler product.

I should note that there is a well-known classical result that if
$$ \sum_{n \geq 1} \lvert b_n \rvert $$
converges, then the partial products of
$$ \prod_{n \geq 1} (1 + b_n) $$
converge to a limit $L$ and $L = 0$ if and only if one of the factors is $0$. This applies to $\zeta(s)$.

If you know this result, then it is true that since $\sum \lvert n^{-s} \rvert$ converges for $\mathrm{Re} s > 1$, that the Euler product representation of $\zeta(s)$ also converges and is nonzero because each individual term is nonzero.

Comment: Can I check I understand. Since $\sum\frac{1}{p^s}$ converges for $\sigma>1$, we can then say the infinite product converges for $\sigma>1$. Is this correct?

Comment: As a second comment - where does the "$L=0$ iff one of the factors is 0" come from? I'm trying to understand this in the context of the well-known classical result.

Comment: See for example http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~isaac/math324/s12/zeta.pdf. Or if you have a particular question, I encourage you to write another post here. Good luck!